# Objective-C: Test for nil/0 value?

Tags: objective-c, null

When I log a variable that is supposed to be an `NSNumber` it gives me 0. I think this means it is `nil` and I want to exclude this case.  If it is zero, I also want to exclude it.  I only want to identify cases where there is a number as in 1,2,3.

However, I have tried the following and none of them succeed in excluding the case where the variable logs to 0 but include cases where it logs to 1,2,3 et.  Can anyone suggest what I am doing wrong.

```
if (self.number!=nil) //fails to exclude

if (self.number) //fails to exclude
if (self.number.length>0)//returns error
if (self.number!=nil&&self.number!=0) //fails to exclude

of note if (!self.number) //does exclude but it also excludes case where self.number is 2, 3 or any other number.
```

Thanks for any suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `NSNumber` is an object wrapper around a value.  You can compare it to `nil`, and that is appropriate, but after you've determine it is not `nil` you need to invoke a method on it to get the actual value it represents.

```
if (self.number != nil) {
    NSLog(@"Number value: %ld", self.number.integerValue);
}
```

Comment: The OP is doing this `if` check in the 1st line of code they posted.

Comment: OK.  I got it with a variation on your answer.  if (self.number!-nil&&self.number.integerValue!=0)   Thx!

Comment: @rmaddy I realize that, I was attempting to note the difference in my example.

Answer (score 2):

To test 0 value, try this:

```
  NSNumber *num=[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]; or @(0);

if ([num intValue]==0 ) {
    NSLog(@"number is 0");     //executes
}

NSNumber *num=[NSNumber numberWithInt:1];    or @(1);

if ([num intValue]==1 ) {
    NSLog(@"number is 1");   //executes 
}
```

same for 2 and 3 also